# How can I code a webpage that supports multiple language such as English, Chinese and Japanese.

Tags: html, css, unicode, multilingual, utf-16

I have a html code that gets some data from the server. The data could be in chinese,english or japanese for now. How can I modify my html code to handle multiple languages such as chinese and japanese?

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? The question seems to generic for me.

Comment: This is *incredibly* hazy. You're not even mentioning the language you are using to fetch the data. Your answer may lay here: [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170) but it's impossible to tell without more details

Comment: Why do you feel like your webpage doesn't support those languages?

Comment: Sorry about the vague questioning guys, this is a new area for me so I don't know exactly what informations are needed. I am using jquery to fetch some jsonp data from a server. So far I've been coding the html normally disregarding any utf and using the default encodings. I'm not sure how to proceed to support multiple languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A random shot inc.

You need to read the header data from the brower about what language its using.  And from that you can pick you right language from the database and return it to the webpage.

My answer is THIS BIG because your question is that big :)

But yea UTF-8 all the way is a good idea too ;)

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. I'm using jquery to retrieve jsonp data from a server to populate some div. How would I read the header data from what is returned by the ajax call?